# Django cant Cast DateTime

Tags: django, orm

I've tried cast string to datetime in orm.

```
        from_date = KeyTextTransform('from_date', KeyTextTransform('foo', 'bar'))
        end_date = KeyTextTransform('end_date', KeyTextTransform('foo', 'bar'))

self.annotate(from_date=Cast(from_date, DateField()))
            .annotate(end_date=Cast(end_date, DateField()))
            .filter(from_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
            .filter(end_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now()
```

But i got error when i use  'd.m.y' format like "13.01.1999".

Error

```
django.db.utils.DataError: date/time field value out of range: "20.01.2018"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

Comment: Why did you use a `CharField` in the first place?

Comment: try use datetime.date.today() instead of datetime.datetime.now(). thats because you are using DateField() and not DateTimeField()

Comment: I didnt use CharField. I use to JSONField. I'm write the post data in JSONField. And i can't access post data.

Comment: datetime.date.today() is did'nt work for me.